# save created excel file to azure blob container. path issue

Tags: azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

Using an Azure Function I create an excel file and I am trying to save it to my Azure Blob Container.  The code to save it is...

```
sl.SaveAs(filepath);
```

The problem is I don't know what to put for the variable filepath.  When I save it on my local harddrive in development I use this path which works...

string filepath= @"C:\Users\xxx\source\repos\xxx\xxx\temp\x.xlsx";

In Azure, if I goto properties for the blob container I see this.
https://abc.blob.core.windows.net/xyz

I know I am missing something simple here.  Right now I am running in debug mode locally using VS2019, not sure if that is the issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can't use `SaveAs` method to save your excel file directly to `Storage`.

I guess you use the `SpreadsheetLight` assembly. Please refer to the following code, you can save your Excel file to local first and then read it as stream:

```
            String filePath = "D:\\document\\MahNewShoes.xlsx";
            using (SLDocument sl = new SLDocument())
            {
                sl.SetCellValue("B3", "It costs what for a Jimmy Choo?!?");
                sl.SaveAs(filePath);
            }

            string connectionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING");
            BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(connectionString);
            BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient("test");
            containerClient.CreateIfNotExists();
            BlobClient blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient("MahNewShoes.xlsx");
            using FileStream uploadFileStream = File.OpenRead(filePath);
            await blobClient.UploadAsync(uploadFileStream, true);
            uploadFileStream.Close();
```

Comment: yes I am using spreadsheet light.  thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is a few months old, but I had a similar issue and came to a fairly simple solution (except I needed to do it without saving locally).

```
        string connectionString = "YourConnectionString";
        string containerName = "YourContainerName";
        string strFileNameXLS = "YourOutputFile.xlsx";

        BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(connectionString);
        BlobContainerClient blobContainerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName);
        BlobClient blobClient = blobContainerClient.GetBlobClient(strFileNameXLS);

        SLDocument doc = YourSLDocument();

        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            doc.SaveAs(ms);
            ms.Position = 0;
            await blobClient.UploadAsync(ms, true);
            ms.Close();
        }
```